# При переходе на другую страницу скрипт почему-то не загружается заново

Tags: javascript, youtube

Есть расширение для браузера, оно работает с сайтом YouTube. При переходе на другую страницу скрипт почему-то не загружается заново, а на новой странице остается то же содержание `insertAdjacentHTML` что и на предыдущей странице. Что я делаю не так? Что стоит попробовать?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    function injectScript() {
       
      if(document.querySelector('#a') === null && document.querySelector('#player.style-scope') !== null){
        
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#player')).pop().insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<div id="a">Код</div>`);

        // Код

      }
    }

    const  element = document.querySelector('body');

    function childList(list){
      injectScript();
    }

    let callback = function(mutations, observer) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.type === 'childList'){
          childList(mutation);
        }
      });
    }

    const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);

    const config = {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    mutationObserver.observe(element, config);

})
```

Comment: Может страница-то и не перезагружается? SPA какое-нибудь.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин может знаете что делать в таких случаях? Что стоить попробовать?

Answer (score 1):

Современные сайты-приложения не перезагружают страницы. Они просто меняют содержимое так, что нам кажется, что мы перешли на новую страницу. Проверить это можно открыв вкладку Сеть в инструментах разработчика в браузере и походить по сайту. Если запросов на страницу (Doc) нет, значит всё меняется динамически (через Fetch/XHR).

В интернете [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes) повесить [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) следить за изменениями на странице и проверять не поменялся ли location.href.

Comment: Doc - имеете в виду смотреть "Тип" "document"?

Comment: @Юра да. Можно посмотреть все запросы, когда браузер запрашивает страницу. Это происходит только при открытии или перезагрузке. А в остальных случаях он страницу не загружает, а подтягивает данные через fetch и меняет html.

Comment: Да, fetch. Document только первый раз выдает